# Is it possible in an "if-statement" to execute the actual statement if the condition is false?

Tags: java, if-statement

I encountered the code example below in the JavaNotes book. The answer was that after execution the x is equal to 2.

My question is how exactly does this work?

I see it is not an if-else flow, but in the second "if" the `boolean` expression is false, so X shall not obtain value 2. 
How is this happening?

```
int x; 
x = -1; 
if (x < 0) 
  x = 1;
if (x >= 0) 
  x = 2;
```

Comment: Why is the second if false? What do you think the value of x is at that point?

Comment: Why do you think `1` is not more than `0`?

Comment: Try rubber duck debugging!  It works!  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging

Comment: As I wrote this is an example from a book which I can't understand. That is why I posted it here

Comment: Write down the value of x at each line. It'll make much more sense then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)! Read the comment in the code so you can understand how your code work :

```
int x;
x = -1;
if (x < 0) { //-1 < 0 = true
    x = 1;   //enter here -> change x = 1
}//end of the first if

if (x >= 0) {//1 >= 0 = true
    x = 2;   //enter here -> change x = 2
}//end of the second if

System.out.println(x);//result is 2
```

---

If you expect `x = 1` then your code should look like this :

```
if (x < 0) { //-1 < 0
    x = 1;   //enter here -> change x = 1
} else if (x >= 0) {//1 >= 0
//^^^^------------------------------------------note the else
    x = 2;   //enter here -> change x = 2
}
```

Answer (score 1):

x = -1;
first if: x < 0 is true,
so x gets new value 1

second if: x > 0 is true
so x gets new value 2
x = 2;

Comment: This answer adds nothing to the current top answer, and is hard to understand and low-quality. Please considering removing it.

Comment: You do not need to delete this question, Just edit it to add new information which will be helpful to future readers.